# Finding area covered by unmasked pixels in an image in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, area

I want to calculate the area covered by forests in a region. Using Hansen image I have demarcated the forest regions in India. Now, how do I get the total area of forests?

```
 // FILTERING OUT FOREST COVER IN INDIA

var treeCanopyCover = hansen.clip(india).select('treecover2000');
var greater25 = treeCanopyCover.gte(25);
var treeCover_greater25 = treeCanopyCover.updateMask(greater25);
```

I know that I can use `ee.Image.pixelArea()`, and then subsequently use reduceRegion. But, I don't understand what scale I should give. In fact, I would like to know, what exactly are the roles of scale and maxPixels. Could someone enlighten me on this regard?

```
var areaImage = treeCover_greater25.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

var stats = areaImage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: india,
  scale: 100,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

Instead of multiplying by `ee.Image.pixelArea` use `mask` function.

```
var areaImage = ee.Image.pixelArea().mask(treeCover_greater25);

var stats = areaImage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: india,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

`ee.Image.pixelArea()` gives an image where value of each pixel corresponds to its area. When we mask this image with `'treeCover_greater25'`, any pixels in `'treeCover_greater25'` that have the value 0 will be made transparent in `ee.Image.pixelArea()`.

For more details go through this link : https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorial_api_05